# Deleted a "Programs and Features" item. Now cannot uninstall it

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, virus, malware, uninstall

I accidentally deleted "Initialpage123" virus uninstall item from the "uninstall a program" menu. I don't know where its uninstall.exe file is and cannot uninstall it as a consequence. Would you please help me? And yes, I have searched for "how to remove the Initialpage123 virus" on Google. I also have Malware Hunter, Malwarebytes Anti-malware and Windows Defender. But my default search engine keeps changing back to "initialpage" each time I open Chrome settings.

Comment: Search in LocalAppData and Roaming folder in user directory. May be there hide some junk files.

Comment: How exactly did you "delete" the uninstall item?

Comment: Related: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit)

Comment: @ramhound I used Revo, but instead of uninstall,  I clicked on delete entry.

Comment: You should be able to go to the directory which Initialpage123 is installed at and just run the uninstaller manually.

Comment: @Ramhound That's the problem. I don't know where the directory is.